# Is it possible to get working history for multi-line commands in mksh, using vi editing mode?

Tags: debian, ksh, command-history, mksh

On my Debian systems, I have always used `pdksh` as my interactive shell.  Originally, command-line history behavior was similar to what I grew up with on platforms like AIX and Solaris.

Recently, since `pdksh` on Debian is now implemented by `mksh`, command-line history no longer works like my fingers expect.  I am trying to figure out if I can configure `mksh` to do what I want, or if I have to find another idiom (or another shell).

I use `ksh` in vi-editing mode (`set -o vi` and `FCEDIT=vi`).  Quite often, I write short multi-line commands immediately at the command prompt, i.e.

```
daystrom:/home/pronovic> for i in 1 2 3
> do
>    print $i
> done
1
2
3
```

These work as expected in `mksh`.  However, command-line history does not.

In all of the kshell implementations that I am familiar with (prior to now), this script would be preserved in the history as a single entry. So, I could hit `ESC-k` and go back to the front of the `for` line.  Once I got there, I could edit the script in place again, or I could hit `ESC-v` to edit the script in `vi`.

In `mksh`, each line in my script (the `for` line, the `do` line, the `print` line, etc.) ends up as a separate entry in my history.  So, `ESC-k` just takes me to the `done` line, `ESC-k` again takes me to the `print` line, etc.

I am looking for a way to configure `mksh` so `ESC-k` takes me to the beginning of my script so I can execute it or edit it again.  However, I haven't found a way to do this.

The only discussion I have found is on [gmane](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.os.miros.mksh/360), which implies that `^O` can somehow be used.  However, it's not clear to me how that is relevant -- or maybe it's just not relevant in vi-editing mode.

Is it possible to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`mksh`](https://www.mirbsd.org/mksh.htm) maintainer here ;-) though this is not the usual “support forum”…

In mksh, both interactive edit (not ESC+v (vi) / ^Xe (emacs) though) is limited to single lines, as is history, as it is terminated internally by the newline character. This has always been so, even in pdksh.

Apparently, pdksh in Debian was patched somehow, I see it has the `^J` newline characters inline. This was a Debian-specific modification I was not aware of. (I do not use the vi editing mode, so I rely on users to request things and occasionally send in a patch; so far, nobody has come forward to maintain it, so it's somewhat orphaned at the moment, but it's popular enough I'm considering rewriting the whole of `edit.c` to unify the code for both modes, to get rid of the maintenance problem.)

`^O` is emacs mode only. But maybe we can make it work for vi mode…

To answer your direct question: No, it is not currently possible in mksh. But I can have a look at what Debian did and try to figure out whether we can take it.

### Edit 2015-07-05

I had a look at pdksh; this is actually a feature of “simple” history which is impossible to simply (no pun intended) clone in “complex” history, which the former Debian packaging of pdksh simply decided to not enable, unlike many other OSes.

I have implemented the feature completely anew today, delaying actual history writes until the command was fully compiled, which means you may lose some history entries in rare error conditions (I checked, syntax errors do not belong to that category) but multi-line input now works as desired in Emacs and Vi modes, including `ESC v` / `^Xe` and history storing/loading.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer, because you've addressed my direct question about whether it's possible.

Comment: If it's possible to build this functionality back into mksh for use in Debian, I would be happy to help in that effort.  It looks like the mksh package in Debian is in a ITA state right now (supposedly waiting for adoption), but nothing has changed since last October.  I'll ping the prospective maintainer.  If necessary, I'll take over the package and maintain it myself.   Let me know if you want me to subscribe to miros-discuss@ or start a private conversation.

Comment: Do *not* add this to mksh only in Debian. That would be a maintenance nightmare. I can do this upstream, after a check whether it can be done and makes sense. (But I had some thoughts about it, and I'm fairly certain it could.) miros-mksh@ is the mailing list you want, I'd say.

Comment: Yes, I agree it would be much better to have the change made in the upstream package, as opposed to maintaining a Debian-specific patch.  I was simply volunteering to make sure the functionality was available in Debian once it's been implemented.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not needed. `mksh` updates are provided regularily in Debian following a master plan.